# Wordpress Shortcodes - Optional Styles

Tags: theme-development, shortcode

i'm creating some custom shortcodes for my wordpress theme. Shortcodes are by nature optional on pages/posts, but may contain css, js or other files.

My question is, how can i enqueue css styles ONLY IF a particular shortcode has been used ? I would not want to load everything for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general process for this is:

1. Create a function, hooked into `wp_enqueue_scripts`
2. Inside your function, cycle through the Loop, looking for your shortcode string
3. If found, call `wp_enqueue_style( 'my_custom_style' )`
4. Rewind the Loop, by calling `<?php rewind_posts(); ?>`

Comment: oh, so you are parsing the actual page content for that ?

Comment: Well, you're *cycling* through the Loop, but not actually outputting any of the Loop *content*. You're just looking for a `preg_match()` or similar for your shortcode string.

Comment: ok i see thx :)